# Prevent autobinding from overrriding certain fields Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The autobinding features of Spring are great. So, I'm trying to deal with this scenario:

- The user is "sharing" content from someone else, let's say he's sharing a "ForumPost" from someone else to his newsfeed.
- I autobind the sharing form which references the shared ForumPost by id.

  input type="hidden" name="post" value="15"

So, Spring autobinds the post object to the resulting object. I have a dataBinder function that loads the post based on the supplied id.

How do I make sure that the only thing that is bound here is the id. What is the best way to prevent the user from saying

```
 input type="hidden" name="post" value="15"
 input type="hidden" name="post.txt" value="deface me"
```

In the dataBinder. I could specifically say

```
 dataBinder.setAllowedFields("....all the allowed fields...","post")
```

This is a little inconvenient because it would be easy to forget a property that breaks the application unintentionally over time.

I don't think it's possible to say

```
 dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("post.*")
```

Just wondering what is the most robust way of dealing with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried it? And have you read [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setDisallowedFields-java.lang.String...-)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on it now. But I think this is such an easy way to trip up, I would like to hear feedback on it.

Comment: As mentioned, read the docs as it explains it...

Comment: I have done. But the nuance is missing, which is where you can get into trouble. I'll do some more tests and get back on this post.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to create a custom Form Backing Object (a POJO with only the required fields for the form), and use that for binding.

You can use a tool like Dozer to automagically copy values from the Form Backing Object to your Domain Object.